# adding dll library to java using idea for using a program

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vlc, jvlc

I am trying to add and use a program called JVLC to my program. I downloaded a zip file that contains a jar file(jvlc.jar) for java interface and 2 dll files (jvlc.dll , libvlc.dll) and a folder that contains many dll files. when I run my program an UnsatisfiedLinkError occurs.
I used this code to add those 2 dll files to my project.

```
System.loadLibrary("C:\\Users\\sajad\\Documents\\Downloads\\Compressed\\JVLC\\jvlc.dll");
System.loadLibrary("C:\\Users\\sajad\\Documents\\Downloads\\Compressed\\JVLC\\libvlc.dll");
```

but still there is error:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: Directory
>   separator should not appear in library
>   name

Is it necessary to add all folder to library paths? If yes how?

please guide me.

Answer (score 6):

The `System.loadLibrary` method loads a libary based on a library name (*libName*, without extension) and **not** through file name. Example, Java comes with a zip.dll / zip.so (Linux) that is used when we use the Zip Deflater/Inflater classes for zip files.

If you want to use specify a dll file name, use the `System.load(String filename)` method otherwise, register your DLL in a java lib path.

An example can be found [here](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/helloWorld/load.html).

---

For your example, please do this:

```
//Your code....
System.loadLibrary("C:\\Users\\sajad\\Documents\\Downloads\\Compressed\\JVLC\\jvlc.dll");
System.loadLibrary("C:\\Users\\sajad\\Documents\\Downloads\\Compressed\\JVLC\\libvlc.dll");

//Replace with this...
System.load("C:\\Users\\sajad\\Documents\\Downloads\\Compressed\\JVLC\\jvlc.dll");
System.load("C:\\Users\\sajad\\Documents\\Downloads\\Compressed\\JVLC\\libvlc.dll");
```

Comment: Yes! I deleted file name at the end of System.loadLibrary("C:\..."). but still it doesn't work. How can I add all library to my project? I also used "System.load(filename)" but still error    :jvlc.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Comment: @sajad you need to find the libraries upon which your libraries depend and load them first.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html):

- You need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (on Linux/Unix) or `PATH` (Windows) include the directory where the libraries are.
- You don't need the `.dll` suffix.

Comment: Sir! I use windows. I want to add this, perhaps via IDEA to my project.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that `PATH` is for Windows (read the link I gave).

Comment: Link to tutorial is broken. Can you provide a summary?